# Define a function as a finite sum

Tags: r, function, sum

How does one properly define a function in R as a finite sum? I am getting inconsistent behavior from R when attempting to define the function as a finite sum as shown below. The function evaluates properly but will not plot or find max or min values without returning an error. See the M!WE below.

```
m = 1:3
y <- seq(-1 , 1 , by =0.01 )
data <- as.vector(  c(-pi , exp(1) , 0.1 ) )
g <- function(y){
  ifelse( abs(y)==0.5 | y==0 , sum(data[m]) , sum(data[m]*( sin(2 *pi *y - pi * (m-2)) / ( 2 *pi *y - pi *(m-2) ) ) ) )
}
g(0)
# [1] -0.3233108
g(0)==g(-0.5) 
# [1] TRUE 
g(-1/sqrt(2)) 
# [1] -2.904101 
plot(g,y) 
Warning messages: 
1: In 2 * pi * y - pi * (m - 2) : 
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length 
2: In 2 * pi * y - pi * (m - 2) : 
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length 
3: In data[m] * (sin(2 * pi * y - pi * (m - 2))/(2 * pi * y - pi *  : 
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length 
max(g(y))
# [1] NaN
```

The trouble being that the graph exists and is well behaved, and that the max (and min for that matter) both exist and are even unique. Even more confusing is the fact that the error message is mathematically false. The length of the sequence y is definitely a multiple of the length of the vector m (in fact exactly a factor of 100).

I tried the following things to no avail.

1. Enclose the sequence `y` in `as.numeric()` hoping it will coerce correctly with the vector m-2, well just as m and -2 do, but this did nothing to help.
2. Enclose the sequence `y` in `as.vector()` hoping R will finally realize the two lengths are related by a factor of 100. Again, this didn't help.

I know I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here but it is unclear to me for lack of experience, and being baffled as to how a function can return a real number for every element in its domain, but not be able to be graphed. Also, I realize there is probably some package that will make all the troubles go away by rephrasing the input but the mathematician in me can't let these baffling contradictions go unexplained.

Comment: you are trying to plot a function (`plot(g, ...)`) without applying it to an object hence the lack of plot and, as @etienne pointed out in his answer, you are misusing your function, you need to "vectorize" it, e.g. with sapply. As for the max/min, with the way you compute g(y), it contains lots of `NaN`, hence the result, you can use parameter `na.rm=T` to suppress NA values when computing max/min.

Comment: For your code you can remove the `as.vector` for d as `c()`already defines d as a vector. And `sum(data[m])`is the same as `sum(data)`because `data`and `m`have the same length

Comment: Ok I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
plot(y,sapply(y,g))
```

[image]

```
max(sapply(y,g))
[1] 3.056132

min(sapply(y,g))
[1] -3.363206
```

The problem in your function seems to be the following : when you use `g(y)`, if y is different from -0.5, 0 or 0.5, the function `data[m]*( sin(2 *pi *y - pi * (m-2)) / ( 2 *pi *y- pi *(m-2) ) )` will create a vector from each value of y and will then sum it. But the 101th element is NaN so the sum is NaN so for almost all values, g(y) will be NaN. Using `sapply(y,g)`will apply the function for each element of y, thus avoiding any problem.